# Macro block unexpectedly returns [do: return value]

Tags: macros, elixir, metaprogramming

I have the following definition inside a macro:

```
defmacro route(pattern, options \\ [], block) do
  name = "my_fun"
  def unquote(name)(var!(conn)) do
    unquote(block)
  end
end
```

I am calling the macro with this function:

```
route "/" do
  conn
  |> put_resp_content_type("text/plain")
  |> send_resp(200, "Hello, world!")
```

The inner block is returning a `%Plug.Conn{}` struct, but when I print the results of `unquote(block)` in my macro, I get `[do: %Plug.Conn{}]` What am I doing wrong? Where did the `do` keyword list come from?

#### Larger snippet

```
defmacro route(pattern, options \\ [], block) do
  name = Keyword.get_lazy(options, :name, fn -> create_name(pattern, options) end)
  route = {pattern, name}
  quote do
    @routes [unquote(route) | @routes]
    def unquote(name)(var!(conn)) do
      resp = unquote(block)
      IO.puts("outside the block, resp is")
      IO.inspect(resp)
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
route "/" do
  resp = conn
  |> put_resp_content_type("text/plain")
  |> send_resp(200, "Hello, world!")
  IO.puts("Inside the block, resp is")
  IO.inspect(resp)
  resp
end
```

#### Results

```
Inside the block, resp is
%Plug.Conn{
  adapter: {Plug.Adapters.Cowboy2.Conn, :...},
  assigns: %{},
  {....SNIP....}
}

outside the block, resp is
[
  do: %Plug.Conn{
    adapter: {Plug.Adapters.Cowboy2.Conn, :...},
    assigns: %{},
    {....SNIP....}
  }
]
```

Comment: Try changing `block` to `do: block` in the arguments list.

Comment: Okay that fixes it. Followup question: How did that ever work in the first place??

Comment: It is definitely much too late, this makes sense. `unquote([{:do, AST}])` is going to return `[{do:, parse_the_ast(AST)}]`. Cheers, and good night

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the argument from `block` to `do: block`:

```
defmacro route(pattern, options \\ [], do: block) do
```

A `do ... end` argument in an Elixir macro invocation is passed as a one item keyword list with the key being `:do`.

If you don't remove that nesting by pattern matching it as `do: block`, the argument's value will be `[do: block]` and when you unquote it, you're unquoting `[do: ...]`, which is also a valid expression and explains why your code works and why it prints `[do: ...]`.